# jQuery ajax done always fails on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the script below that erases a line on a MySQL database with ajax. When the function is fired the line gets deleted from the database but I am always alerted "FAILED".

```
function deleteRow(data){
if(confirm("Are you sure that you wish to remove this entry?\nThis cannot be undone")){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-content/themes/Rexmed/deleterow.php",
            data: {id: data},
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Success");
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("FAILED");
        });
}
}
```

This is deleterow.php

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
auth_redirect();
die();
}

require ('../../../wp-config.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$id = $_POST['id'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM customers WHERE id=?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: done/complete rarely seem to get triggered. I'm not entirely sure if it is browser dependent or a problem between browsers, but success/error tend to be your best bet.

Comment: To debug: `.fail(function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.log([xhr, status, err]);
        });`

Comment: `data: {id: data}` data = ?

Comment: What is the php script returning? Use Firebug or similar to check.

Comment: You have to actually return JSON, you're not returning anything, so it fails

Comment: The console throws the following: `POST http://url.net/wp-content/themes/Rexmed/deleterow.php 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:7845
[Object, "error", "Not Found"]
0: Object
1: "error"
2: "Not Found"
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]`

Comment: So it's a 404, the URL was not found, and yet you claim the PHP code gets executed ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, the line does get removed, I already looked in the DB.

Comment: Well, try returning JSON and see what happens? If it truly is a 404 I don't think that would do much, but you should be returning JSON anyway so might as well try.

Comment: @adeneo The weird thing is that I looked into the headers and I do get the response json `{"success":"true"}`

Comment: It is worth noting that Wordpress has it's own classes for dealing with ajax, and it's own class for dealing with all database interaction, and it's own way of rewriting URL's, so there could be a number of problems with this approach that is almost impossible for us to figure out, but usually it works to just bypass all the Wordpress stuff, but the database and ajax classes are actually pretty good once you get to know them, and you should be reading up on them in the codex.

Answer (score 5):

Change the PHP and return JSON

```
<?php
    require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        auth_redirect();
        die();
    }

    require ('../../../wp-config.php');
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM customers WHERE id=?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $arr = array('success' => 'true');
        }else{
            $arr = array('success' => 'false');
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

and

```
.done(function(data) {
     if (data.success == 'true') {
        alert('you did it');
     }
})
```

Comment: Ok, I changed to reflect your modifications but I am still getting "FAILED". Not sure why I am getting a 404 on the console because the line gets removed from the DB.